# Apply padding on toolbar logo with Vuetify2

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

this is code of my toolbar which is placed in drawer:

```
<v-toolbar flat color="white">
  <v-img contain src="@/assets/logo_h.png" class="pa-12" />
</v-toolbar>
```

Toolbar looks like this:

[image]

As you can see logo is fit to toolbar height, so I want add some padding around logo. I tried class `pa-2` but it doesn't have affect on it. When I tried `ma-2` logo is moving to right side and again there is no expected behavior. Can you tell me how to add this padding using vuetify? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If that's only item in your toolbar you can add padding class to the `v-toolbar`